# Does a sequence of $n-$cells converge to a Hilbert cube?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X$ is a compact, connected metric space and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a $Yn \subset X$ so that $Y_n \simeq [0,1]^n$. With the Hausdorff metric defined on the hyperspace of compact connected subspaces of $X$, does the sequence $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to a Hilbert cube?

I believe it should, for the sequence $\left ([0,1]^n \times \prod_{m>n}\{0\} \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ looks like should converge to the whole $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$, and each element of that sequence is homeomorphic to $Y_n$. However I am unsure whether sequences of sets preserve homeomorphisms... Could someone provide some insight please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, $X$ could be a Hilbert cube and the $Y_n$ could be chosen to have diameter converging to $0$.  Then in the Hausdorff metric $(Y_n)$ can only converge to a single point.  (They could also fail to converge at all, since for instance they could oscillate between shrinking down to two different points.)